# Qual a diferença de declarar uma variável como constexpr const e constexpr?

Tags: c++, c++11, constantes, c++14, const

Qual a diferença de declarar uma constante como `constexpr const` para apenas uma `constexpr`?

```
constexpr const float max_height = 3.0f;

constexpr float max_height = 3.0f;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`constexpr` informa ao compilador que ele tem o resultado daquela expressão em tempo de compilação por isso pode otimizar e resolver sem levar aquilo para a execução. `const` só garante que aquele valor não será mudado ao longo da execução.

Na prática nos dois casos mostrados dá na mesma porque de fato é um literal, faria diferença em uma expressão, uma função, algo que depende de alguma informação que não está presente diretamente ali na declaração. E com certeza algo resolvido na compilação não pode ser alterado. Poderia até fazer:

```
const float max_height = 3.0f;
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Syntax/Const.cpp).

Comment: Mas em C++11 a diante não é recomendado preferir o uso da constexpr em vez da const?

Comment: Por que você usaria algo que não te dá vantagem nova ao que deseja? `consterpr` tem outra semântica, conforme eu respondi.